App Store Connectでアイコンが真っ黒になる
お世話になっております。App Storeでリリースしたアプリのアイコンが真っ黒に表示されてしまい困っております。
こちらApple社に問い合わせしていますが、その後レスがなく。
現象としては、背景色が白色(#FFFFF)でアイコンを作成してAppStoreConnectにて、
バイナリーを指定した段階で、黒いアイコンになってしまいます。
背景色を少しいじる（#F5F5F5等）アプリをアップロードするとアイコンは表示されます。
考えられる原因ってなんでしょうか？
ちなみに、AppStoreには、アイコン真っ黒の状態で公開されております。
